# Locally cyclic group and homology

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

I would like to ask about the accuracy of the following statement.

If $G$ is locally cyclic. Then the $n$-th homology group of $G$ $($H_n(G) $)$ (specially for $n=2$, $n=3$) is also locally cyclic.

Yours,